# Emacs Latex/Auctex: Error message about using `Tex-command-list` command to set `Make` as a compile option

Tags: spacemacs, latex, auctex

I have a setting in my `Spacemacs` dotfile that adds `Make` as a compile option for a latex document. The actual command is below.

```
(add-to-list 'TeX-command-list 
            '("Make" "make" TeX-run-compile nil t))
```

For some reason this command seems to generate a error. The specific message is:

```
 (Spacemacs) Error in dotspacemacs/user-config: Symbol’s value as variable is void: TeX-command-list
```

Is there a better way to write this command, or has the api for the `Tex-command-list` command, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to fix that issue:

1. `TeX-command-list` is defined in `tex.el`. Use `(require 'tex)` before your `(add-to-list 'TeX-command-list ...)`. That is the smallest change. But you always load `tex.el` at startup time.
2. Put your code into `eval-after-load` such that it is evaluated after `TeX-command-list` is defined in `tex.el`.

```el
(eval-after-load "tex.el"
   '(add-to-list 'TeX-command-list
                 '("Make" "make" TeX-run-compile nil t)))
```

3. You can customize `TeX-command-list` over <kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-option`. That is the normal way to do it. (But see my note at the bottom.)
4. Put `(add-to-list 'TeX-command-list ...)` into a hook function for `TeX-mode-hook`. That is slightly better than the first approach since you don't need to load `tex.el` at startup. With respect to the second approach it has the disadvantage that the code runs every time when you load a TeX-file. The following code demonstrates that approach:

```el
(defun my-TeX-mode-hook-fun ()
  (add-to-list 'TeX-command-list '("Make" "make" TeX-run-compile nil t)))

(add-hook 'TeX-mode-hook #'my-TeX-mode-hook-fun)
```

Note: I don't know spacemacs. So I am not sure whether the vanilla customization interface works well with spacemacs.

Comment: Yeah, this worked just fine. Thanks so much @Tobias. I used option 2. I could have used the `customize-option`, which does work with spacemacs as well. I just like having the explicit code of option 2 because I tend to regenerate my custom variables frequently, and I just worry I will forget to set that again, or lose it during the regeneration process--and then won't remember how to fix it :).